# Unable to import tensorflow2.0,(no gpU) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using python 3.6

Below is the error message I am facing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Vishal\Desktop\tf\new.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

How to resolve the above?

Comment: share some code please

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have it installed for the right version of pip (also for the right version of python)?

Below is how you can install a library for a specific version of python (python3 in this case):

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

Or you can also do the below:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

It depends upon how you have configured python and pip.
How do you invoke python3.6?
In my system if I type `python3` in the command line, it opens python3.6 console. It might be different for your case, so it is important to install libraries for appropriate versions for pip as well as python.

There are ways to check which pip is working with which version of python, one of which is, type `pip --version` or `pip -V` and it will show you in the output the version of the python it is working for.

Example:

```
$ pip -V
pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```